# How to create layouts dynamically with each layout having unique functionality

Tags: android, android-widget

I have 2 layout first one takes input and based on query show give output as shown in pic2.
However I am not able to introduce these layouts dynamically.

Each dynamic layout must have a unique id so that when "BOOK" is clicked specific ticket is booked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez4DP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the second layout not dynamic, but as a usual `ListActivity` of vertical `LinearLayouts`. And fill the `ListActivity` from the DB query.

The functionality you need is not unique at all, it only takes different DB table rows as a parameter. It is standard.

Comment: thanks for help
but how will I be able to create ListActivity form

Comment: 1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html - notice, you'll have to make 2 layouts - for a list and for a row(column if list is horizontal).  2. When you are calling the second activity from the first one, it appears ON the first one. When you make the choose and close it, the first one appears back - it is the usual activity stack.